# Nginx 403'ing directories

Tags: permissions, nginx

I am running  nginx/1.14.0 on ubuntu 18.04 and my directories keep 403'ing.

site config

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
root /var/www/html;
index index.html .css .png .jpg .php .swf .js;
server_name fantage.info;

location /media {
    autoindex on;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }
```

[here is a developer tools network of the url if it helps.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkntC.png)